# Error while updating column in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

Basically what my code does is simply update the database I have created where all the column are of 'varchar' format. My code is able to create a new entry when the time frame is '10:00-10:15'. However, when it is unable to update it when the time frame becomes '10:15-10:30' or basically any other time frame. My code is below:

```
import time
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb import *
import datetime
import json

date = time.localtime()
year_mon_date_day = [date.tm_year, date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday, date.tm_wday]

column = ''
if date.tm_hour==10:
    if date.tm_min<=15:
        column = "10:00-10:15"
    elif date.tm_min<=30:
        column = "10:15-10:30"
    elif date.tm_min <= 45:
        column = "10:30-10:45"
    elif date.tm_min <= 60:
        column = "10:45-11:00"

elif date.tm_hour==11:
    if date.tm_min<=15:
        column = "11:00-11:15"
    elif date.tm_min<=30:
        column = "11:15-11:30"
    elif date.tm_min <= 45:
       column = "11:30-11:45"
    elif date.tm_min <= 60:
       column = "11:45-12:00"

elif date.tm_hour==12:
    if date.tm_min<=15:
        column = "12:00-12:15"
    elif date.tm_min<=30:
        column = "12:15-12:30"
    elif date.tm_min <= 45:
        column = "12:30-12:45"
    elif date.tm_min <= 60:
        column = "12:45-01:00"

elif date.tm_hour==13:
    if date.tm_min<=15:
        column = "01:00-01:15"
    elif date.tm_min<=30:
        column = "01:15-01:30"
    elif date.tm_min <= 45:
        column = "01:30-01:45"
    elif date.tm_min <= 60:
        column = "01:45-02:00"

else:
    pass

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='4747',db='traffic_record')
cursor=db.cursor()


if column == "10:00-10:15":
    query = '''INSERT INTO `traffic_record`.`RoadA` ( `Date`,`Day`,`''' + column + '''`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')'''
    value = (year_mon_date_day,date.tm_wday, 9)
else:
    query = '''UPDATE `traffic_record`.`RoadA` SET `''' + column + '''`=`%s` WHERE `Date`=''' + str(year_mon_date_day) + '''`'''
    value = (3)

cursor.execute(query, value)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

My code gives following error when I try to run it in any other time frame other than '10:00-10:15'. I receive the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/sparsha/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/fill_table.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sparsha/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/fill_table.py", line 83, in <module>
cursor.execute(query, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am unable to solve it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your value as an iterable:

```
value = (3,)
#         ^
```

What you have `(3)` is an integer with a grouping parenthesis. The parenthesis does not make the integer an iterable. But adding that comma makes it a singleton tuple which is what you want.

Comment: I tried it just now and the error I received is: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[2016, 7, 26, 1]`' at line 1")

Comment: You are passing your date as a list converted to str (i.e. `year_mon_date_day `), why is that?

Comment: That must be when I was playing around with the code to check if any thing solve the existing error. When I remove the str, the error I receive states:     query = '''UPDATE `traffic_record`.`RoadA` SET `''' + column + '''`=`%s` WHERE `Date`=''' + year_mon_date_day + '''`'''
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: Removing `str` will not fix it. `year_mon_date_day` should be defined as the str of a date instance, not list. Say `year_mon_date_day =  str(datetime.date.today())`

Comment: Or replace `year_mon_date_day` with `'-'.join(year_mon_date_day[:-1])` which the items in  `year_mon_date_day` into a new date string

Comment: I changed the definition of year_mon_date_day to a str type. Doing that, the system gives an error even when the time frame is '10:00-10:15' i.e when a new entry is created. The error still remains: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2016-07-26'','1','9')' at line 1"

Comment: Looks like your `"` and `'` are not matching

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. I've only used " in the if-else condition to specify my columns, everywhere else ' is being used.

Comment: BTW, how could a changing timeframe (like `'10:00-10:15'`) be a column in your table? Was this working before now?

Comment: That's simply the name of the column in the table, nothing else. I've used the if-else condition in the current instance of the time to insert my required data in the database. Yes, it works well with the insert statement as I tried it with different columns. Only the update statement doesn't seem to work somehow.

Comment: Check that last `'''\`'''` in your update query. It isn't wrapping anything and has no matching pair

Comment: Nevermind, Insert seems to work fine. I think I'll just create a list of data and insert the data all at once and simply avoid the update statement for now. Thanks for your input though.